# Same subscription key for products in different APIM instances

Tags: wso2-api-manager, azure-api-management, azure-cli, apim

We are having 2 Azure APIM instance for our Production apps, one is in primary region (currently active) and one is in secondary region (currently passive). So we we may need to switch our environments to this regions as per the requirements and we are facing challenges for some Applications, which needs same subscription key assigned for their apis hosting products.

Is there any way to achieve the below using azure cli method or arm method, so that we can automate these further using our ADO pipelines.

- APIM 1- Create Subscription key within a product in APIM instance-1
- APIM 2 - use the same subscription key assigned to the same product in the API instance 2

Comment: i guess you can do this with azure CLI and ARM templates.

Comment: yeah no reason why ou would not be able. create key in APIM 1 then you can reuse the key in APIM 2

Comment: ARM/Bicep would work. I dont see any options for az cli or az powerhsell natively, you could always use `az rest` if you wanna use the arm api directly

Comment: I could see blow comments will work with PowerShell. But we are looking for a way to automate it using our Linux based Devops agents. there we cant run powershell script.

Comment: Set-AzContext -Subscription "mysubscriptionB"
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "myAPIM-B-RG" -ServiceName "myAPIM-B"
Set-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext -SubscriptionId "" -PrimaryKey "" -SecondaryKey "" -State "Active"

Answer (score 1):

You can always update the primary and secondary keys of a subscription using the following [rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/update?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP) which means that you can achieve the desired behavior using ARM. I never tried [azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest) for this but I do not see az subscription command.

Comment: I could see blow comments will work with PowerShell. But we are looking for a way to automate it using our Linux based Devops agents. there we cant run powershell script.

Comment: Set-AzContext -Subscription "mysubscriptionB"
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "myAPIM-B-RG" -ServiceName "myAPIM-B"
Set-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext -SubscriptionId "" -PrimaryKey "" -SecondaryKey "" -State "Active"